# MVC 5 Breadcrumbs not working with Areas

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In order to work with breadcrumbs on my site. I have installed package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5. My Application has 2 areas - Partner & Customer :

[image]

My Sitemap

[image]

It is not accepting the second sitemap node. How it is going to be manage and how could we achieve it for areas. ?. Any help would be appreciable.

Display templates is installed on location ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<mvcSiteMap>` allows only one `<mvcSiteMapNode>` child.

You can use your home controller and action as first element in breadcrumb and then add sitemap nodes for you areas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Partner" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" area="Partner">
      ...
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" area="Customer">
      ...
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Edin is correct. You can only have 1 root `SiteMap` node, just like for a web site you can only have 1 home page. Your areas should be nested just inside of the node representing the home page.

If you don't want the home page node to appear in the bread crumb, you can use a [visibility provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility) to hide it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" 
    visibility="!SiteMapPathHelper" 
    visibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Partner" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" area="Partner">
      ...
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" area="Customer">
      ...
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```